# Printing Nested Json API data using Python

Tags: python, json, api, get, nested

I was able to receive the data using an API get request, now I just need help printing a few objects. I'm having trouble because the objects I need are nested pretty deeply. Objects I need:

-cve ID
-url ref
-description
-severity

json page: https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cve/1.0/CVE-2021-40463/

```
import requests
import json
import pprint

url = "https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cve/1.0/CVE-2021-40463/"
params = {"q": "CVE"}
response = requests.get(url, params)

data = json.loads(response.text)


pprint.pprint (data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import json
import pprint

url = "https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cve/1.0/CVE-2021-40463/"
params = {"q": "CVE"}

response = requests.get(url, params)

data = json.loads(response.content)    

pprint.pprint(data)
```

response.content will return the content of the response. after than:

cve ID: `pprint.pprint(data['result']['CVE_Items'][0]['cve']['CVE_data_meta']['ID'])`

url ref: `pprint.pprint(data['result']['CVE_Items'][0]['cve']['references']['reference_data'][0]['url'])`

description: `pprint.pprint(data['result']['CVE_Items'][0]['cve']['description']['description_data'][0]['value'])`

severity: `pprint.pprint(data['result']['CVE_Items'][0]['impact']['baseMetricV2']['severity'])`

Comment: Thanks, Berkay. I tried CVE ID first and it just responded the entire page. It's interesting, it seems I was on the right page - I sorta tried what you typed on my own earlier, but no success. It's nested pretty complex.

Comment: CVE ID response for this url I get: 'CVE-2021-40463'. I edited my answer for the clarification.

Comment: You are welcome by the way. If the answer was useful could you please mark the answer as correct answer please ☺️. @Alexandra

Comment: Wow - how did you do that. Seems I just need to learn the ordering of nesting. Thanks, Berkay. I'll mark the answer as correct.